# How can I make a http client request after another is completed?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-client

In my Symfony function I am creating a folder, and inside this folder another folder:

```
$client = HttpClient::create();

$createFolder = $client->request('MKCOL', $path.$foldername, [
'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
]);


$createImageFolder = $client->request('MKCOL', $path.$foldername/images', [
'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
]);
```

It works well, but somtimes the first folder is not created fast enough, and the image folder cannot be created. Is there a way, that the second request can wait, until the first folder is created?

Comment: Do you have a method that could check if the folder exists before you try to make the subfolder?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes I could do that. But if the folder does not exist yet, then the subfolder is not created. You know what I mean? Then I have still the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$client->request()` is asynchronous. You can use `$client->getStatusCode()` to wait for the response before going to the next operation. You can also use this to confirm that the first operation was successful.

```
$client = HttpClient::create();

$createFolder = $client->request('MKCOL', $path.$foldername, [
    'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
]);

$code = $createFolder->getStatusCode();
if ($code < 300) { // Creation was successful
    $createImageFolder = $client->request('MKCOL', $path.$foldername/images', [
        'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and I get the error message: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getStatusCode" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient".`

Comment: ah, I think I have to write  `$createFolder->getStatusCode();` can this be?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I just fixed it.

Comment: I checked it again, the subfolder is not created, because the code is `201`. What does that mean?

Comment: Could I write 201 instead? Does it also mean success?

Comment: I've changed to `code < 300`, since all `2xx` codes are some form of success.

Comment: Even tho the `2**` status codes are grouped as success, some codes like `204 No Content` could indicate that the request had some issues.

Comment: @0stone0 It's clearly context-dpeendent. For this, probably 201 is the right code to check for.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Symfony HTTP Client docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#making-requests):

> Responses are always asynchronous, so that the call to the method returns immediately instead of waiting to receive the response:

```php
<?php
// code execution continues immediately; it doesn't wait to receive the response
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.2/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso');

// getting the response headers waits until they arrive
$contentType = $response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0];

// trying to get the response content will block the execution until
// the full response content is received
$content = $response->getContent();
```

So you'll need to call `$response->getContent()` (or any other like `getHeaders()`) to block until receiving!